# I keep getting a 405 error when trying to load and play my video

Tags: html, arrays

I have a button that is meant to play my video automatically. I tried with preload = auto and wasn't able to get anything to work//and got a 405 error. What should I do?

```
<div id="vid">
            <video id="myVideo" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" width="320" height="240" preload="none">
              <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="movie.mov" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
            <button onclick="loadplayVideo()" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="button">Would You Like To Talk with Delphi?"</button>
            <!--<audio id="audio" style="width: 100%;"><source src="combo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>-->
            <script type="text/javascript">            
              function loadplayVideo()
                {
                var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
              
                video.load();
                video.play();
                }
              </script>
              <script>swapVideo();</script> 
          </div>
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <video id="myVideo" style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" width="320" height="240" preload="none">
            <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="movie.mov" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
        <button onclick="loadplayVideo()" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="button">Would You Like To Talk with
            Delphi?"</button>
        <!--<audio id="audio" style="width: 100%;"><source src="combo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>-->
     
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadplayVideo() {
        let video = document.getElementById('myVideo');

        video.load();
        video.play();
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

use external javascript file that is better.